# How does a generic wrapper make NaNs equal in Scala?

Tags: scala, nan

After reading examples from the "Programming in Scala" book, chapter 30 on object equality, I've got a little confused on how the reflexivity is guaranteed for `equals` method in generic containers, considering that NaN comparison is non-reflexive. Consider the following snippet:

```
class Wrapper[T](val elem: T) {
  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case that: Wrapper[_] => this.elem == that.elem
    case _ => false
  }
}

object NaNCompare extends App {
  val nan: Double = 0.0 / 0.0
  val nanw: Wrapper[Double] = new Wrapper(nan)
  val pzero: Double = +0.0
  val pzerow: Wrapper[Double] = new Wrapper(pzero)
  val mzero: Double = -0.0
  val mzerow: Wrapper[Double] = new Wrapper(mzero)
  println(s"nan equals nan: ${nan equals nan}")
  println(s"nan == nan: ${nan == nan}")
  println(s"+0 equals -0: ${pzero equals mzero}")
  println(s"+0 == -0: ${pzero == mzero}")
  println(s"[nan] equals [nan]: ${nanw equals nanw}")
  println(s"[nan] == [nan]: ${nanw == nanw}")
  println(s"[+0] equals [-0]: ${pzerow equals mzerow}")
  println(s"[+0] == [-0]: ${pzerow == mzerow}")
}
```

This prints the following:

```
nan equals nan: true
nan == nan: false
+0 equals -0: false
+0 == -0: true
[nan] equals [nan]: true
[nan] == [nan]: true
[+0] equals [-0]: true
[+0] == [-0]: true
```

The first four lines are logical: according to IEEE 754, `nan == nan` is false, while `+0 == -0` is true; however, both nans are the same object, so `nan equals nan` must be true due to `equals`'s reflexivity requirement; `+0 equals -0` is false since these two floating-point numbers have different representations. So far so good.

However, when wrapped by a generic `Wrapper`, `==` suddenly starts to generate `true` while comparing NaNs. I first thought that this happened due to type erasure, so it basically compares bit representations (which are equal for the same NaN), but if so, it must have printed `false` while comparing the wrappers of plus zero and minus zero. However, it gives true in both cases.

To make it even more puzzling, if you add an upper bound `Double` to the first line of this code (`class Wrapper[T <: Double](val elem: T) {`), it prints the following:

```
nan == nan: false
+0 equals -0: false
+0 == -0: true
[nan] equals [nan]: false
[nan] == [nan]: false
[+0] equals [-0]: true
[+0] == [-0]: true
```

So, if it bounded by `Double`, wrapped NaNs are not equal anymore! If you bound it by `AnyVal`, they are equal just as in the original code. If you make the wrapper non-generic (remove T parameter and substitute it with `Double`), they are unequal. So clearly there is something to do with what the compiler "remembers" about the internal structure of `Double`s in different cases. But what does it exactly remember and how the dispatch of `==` is performed?

Comment: Note: Using a **case class** with a generic parameter and leaving the compiler to generate `equals` also returns in `nanw == nanw` to return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suspect is happening is that there are two different runtime implementations of IEEE double precision that Scala can use and they have slightly different equality semantics.

- For the Java primitive `double`, comparison is implemented using a specific JVM instruction; `+0.0 == -0.0` is `true` and `Double.NaN == Double.NaN` is false
- For `java.lang.Double` (an `Object` box for `double`), `equals` is implemented by comparing the bit representations, which results in `NaN` comparing `true` and `+0` not being equal to `-0`.

In Scala, the compiler will basically use the primitive `double` (because it's a lot faster) whenever it has proven that it's dealing with a `scala.Double` (and no methods of `java.lang.Object` are being called, such as `equals`) and will use `java.lang.Double` when (e.g. in a generic (which hasn't been `@specialized`...)) it can't be sure.  The Scala `==` method is not exactly a synonym for `.equals` as it has special handling for things that are implemented as primitives in the JVM.

In general, usage of `.equals` in Scala code should be replaced with `==`.

Comment: But if Scala uses `java.lang.Double` in this `Wrapper[T]` example, and `+0` is not equal to `-0` for `java.lang.Double`, then wrappers of -0 and +0 would not be compared equal. I should probably look into the bytecode...

Comment: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11698 This looks related